# Red circle in the review queue

Tags: discussion

Does anyone know why the Low Quality Posts in the Review Queues dropdown has a red circle next to it, when there isn't anything in the queue to review?

What is the red circle supposed to represent?

[image: Low Quality Posts w/ red circle]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue since the change to dots indicator: [Please don't show the red dot indicator for review items I can't do](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/310798). It means that *there still are* pending reviews in the queue, but you are *not* eligible to review them. Some possible causes:

> - There are items in a queue which the user does not have the reputation to review. (I only know of this happening in the suggested edits queue, where tag wiki edits land in the same queue as post edits.) This once [caused me some consternation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307408/im-not-that-bad-why-cant-i-review).
> - There is a single pending suggested edit, which is currently being reviewed by someone else and has been "checked out" to that reviewer.
> - **The reviewer has already voted on a post in the queue (e.g. flagging a current Low Quality post as NAA or VLQ externally, or externally voting to close or reopen a post currently in one of those queues)**
> - **The reviewer has skipped reviews**
> - [The user has had a review ban](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310783/red-dot-indicator-appears-even-when-im-banned-from-reviewing)
> - **The user has reviewed all items in a queue, but they have not left it yet**
>
> <sup>(Emphasis mine)</sup>